# React: how can you share the state between views using react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using react-router to route to two views which are independent from each other. Currently I've been using a new state object in `Home` and `Backend` but I want to get rid of this because both include nested components.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
          <div className="App">
            <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Home} />

            <Route path="/app/:user_id" component={Backend} />
          </div>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

How is it possible to share the state between the views without using other frameworks like redux or flux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lift the state up into your 'App' component, then pass down whatever elements of the state each component needs through their props.

For example your state in App might look like:

```
App.state = {
  homeRelatedStuff: {...},
  backendRelatedStuff: {...},
  sharedStuff: {...}
}
```

Then when declaring which component to use, you pass down props:

```
<Route path={"/"} component={() => <Home homeStuff={this.state.homeRelatedStuff} sharedStuff={this.state.sharedStuff}/>}/>
```

*Note the slightly different method of listing the component as a function so you can pass props

Your state doesn't have to keep them separate like I have, it could be flatter and you pass down multiple props to each component