# How to share application State between React Router v4 routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I would like to know what kind of solutions I have to solve the following issue:

I don't use any state mangement library. I "only use" React.

The global application state is stored in the component `<MyFoodApp/>`. It contains an array of *restaurant* objects.

The component `RestaurantPage` is used to display the details of a restaurant and allows to **create a new review**.

At this point I'm stuck because I need to **update a specific** `restaurant` object stored in the state of `<MyFoodApp />` in order to add **this submitted review**.

I used to update the state via functions passed as props to the children components but in this case I can't because `MyFoodApp` is not a parent of `RestaurantPage`.

Do I have to set up `Redux` to fix this issue or is there any workarounds ?

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import EasyFoodApp from './js/components/EasyFoodApp';
import RestaurantPage from './js/components/RestaurantPage';
import NotFound from './js/components/NotFound';

class Root extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div className="router">
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={MyFoodApp} />
                        <Route
                            path="/restaurant/:slug"
                            component={RestaurantPage}
                        />
                        <Route render={() => <NotFound />} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Root />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I found old related posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41108701/react-router-share-state-between-routes-without-redux) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47233605/react-how-can-you-share-the-state-between-views-using-react-router) but there is maybe a new way to handle this issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a couple of solution to your problem without actually using a state management library,

**First: Lift the state up,**

This is the most correct solution since your components and routes are not highly nested and the data needs to handled by the components which are siblings of each other,

```
class Root extends React.Component {
    state = {
       restaurant: [] // store the restaurant data here instead of MyFoodApp
    }
    restaurantUpdater = () => {
        //utility function to update state
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div className="router">
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" render={props => <MyFoodApp {...props} restaurant={this.state.data} restaurantUpdater={this.restaurantUpdater} />} />
                        <Route
                            path="/restaurant/:slug"
                            render={props => <RestaurantPage {...props} restaurant={this.state.data} restaurantUpdater={this.restaurantUpdater} />}
                        />
                        <Route render={(props) => <NotFound {...props}/>} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

**Second: Make use of Context API**

You can make use of `Context` when your data needs to be passed down to components at different levels. As the react docs say

> Don’t use context just to avoid passing props a few levels down. Stick
>   to cases where the same data needs to be accessed in many components
>   at multiple levels.

You can configure the use of context using [`React 16.3 context API`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#dynamic-context)  like

```
export const RestaurantContext = React.createContext({
  restaurant: [],
  restaurantUpdater: () => {},
});

class RestaurantProvider extends React.Component {
   state = {
       restaurant: [] // store the restaurant data here instead of MyFoodApp
    }
    restaurantUpdater = () => {
        //utility function to update state
    }
   render() {
      <RestaurantContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        {this.props.children}
      </RestaurantContext.Provider>
   }
}
```

and then create an HOC for the consumer

```
import RestaurantContext from 'path/to/restaurantContext'
const withContext = (Component) => {
    return (props) => <RestaurantContext.Consumer>
        {(restaurant, restaurantUpdater) => <Component {...props} restaurant={restaurant} restaurantUpdater={restaurantUpdater} />}
    </RestaurantContext.Consumer>
}
```

Now you can use it in the component like

```
export default withContext(MyFoodApp);
```

and your FoodApp can use `restaurant` and `restaurantUpdater` from props like

```
const { restaurant, restaurantUpdater} = this.props
```

similarly you can use it in the other components

Comment: Hello @shubham-khatri Thanks for you detailed answer. I think I'll try the Context approach. I just a some questions: maybe I don't understand everything but you don't seem to use the custom `RestaurantProvider` ? I should wrap the `<Router>` or the <Route> components with it right ?

Comment: You can wrap the any of the Router or the Route components,

Answer (score 1):

You could manage data without redux if either of the scenarios matched your arrangement of components:

1. **Parent to child** relationship: Using Props
2. **Child to parent** relationship: Using callbacks
3. **Siblings** with a common parent.

But neither of the relationships satisfies your arrangement of the components since the two components are new root components.

When the components can't communicate between any sort of parent-child relationship, the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) recommends setting up a global event system.

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer. I checked the link you provided but I didn't find any documentation about a "global event system" can you give an example ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution to your answer is to create sub routing to make a sub routing from your **MyFoodApp** component to **RestaurantPage** component.

Inside **MyFoodApp** 's render methode *Note: Don't use switch again inside route

`<Switch>
     <Route exact path="/restaurant"  render={() => <RestaurantPage pages={this.arrayOfRestaurant}/>
</Switch>`

I hope it would help

Comment: Hello thanks for you response. I prefer to keep my routes together. "lifting up" the state or using the new Context API seem to fit with my needs.