# How preserve state when navigating from one route to the other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

I thought that by passing the Navigation component state to each rendered element(Maincomponent and DocComponent), it would preserve the state during routing. But it is not the case. It seems like the Navigation Component is also re-rendering each time Routing occurs. Thank you in advance

This my code:

```
class Navigation extends React.Component {
    state = {
        language: "en",
        selectedCountry: "Cameroon"
    };

    changeLanguage = (lang) => this.setState({language: lang});

    changeCountry = (country) => this.setState({selectedCountry: country})


    catalogs = {en: catalogEn, fr: catalogFr}

    deriveSelectedLanguage = (langCode) => {
        switch (langCode) {
            case 'en':
                return 'English';
            case 'fr':
                return 'French';
            default:
                return "No Lang";

        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/'>
                            <I18nProvider language={this.state.language} catalogs={this.catalogs}>
                                <MainComponent onChangeLanguage={this.changeLanguage}
                                               selectedLanguage={this.deriveSelectedLanguage(this.state.language)}
                                               selectedCountry={this.state.selectedCountry}
                                               onChangeCountry={this.changeCountry}/>
                            </I18nProvider>
                        </Route>

                        <Route path='/Doc'>
                            <I18nProvider language={this.state.language} catalogs={this.catalogs}>
                                <DocPage onChangeLanguage={this.changeLanguage}
                                         selectedLanguage={this.deriveSelectedLanguage(this.state.language)}
                                         selectedCountry={this.state.selectedCountry}
                                         onChangeCountry={this.changeCountry}/>
                            </I18nProvider>
                        </Route>

                    </Switch>

                </div>
            </Router>

        )
    }
}

export default Navigation;
```

Comment: Maybe save the state values you want to keep in localStorage

Comment: Maybe this answer, will help:
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49938568/how-to-share-application-state-between-react-router-v4-routes>